# Ruby compare strings inside hash

Tags: ruby

I've prepared a method which parses a log file and returns a hash as a result:

`parse`

```
  def parse
    file_exist?(file_path)
    @page_views = Hash.new { |k, v| k[v] = [] }

    File.open(file_path).each do |line|
      page, ip = line.split
      @page_views[page] << ip
    end
    @page_views
  end
```

`result`

```
=> {"/help/1"=>
  ["126.318.035.038",
   "929.398.951.889",
   "543.910.244.929",
   "929.398.951.889",
   "929.398.951.889",],
 "/about"=>
   ["929.398.951.889",
   "929.398.951.889",
   "543.910.244.929",]
```

How to sort such data to count IP addresses and displayed like below:

```
=> {"/help/1"=>
  ["126.318.035.038" => 1,
   "929.398.951.889" => 3,
   "543.910.244.929" => 1]
 "/about"=>
   ["929.398.951.889" => 2,
   "543.910.244.929" => 1]
```

Comment: Google "histogram".

Comment: Call [`tally`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Enumerable.html#tally-method) on the IP arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tally`.

```
@page_views.update(@page_views) {|_, v| v.tally}
```

Comment: I suggest `@page_views.transform_values { |v| v.tally }`, or `transform_values!` if (as in your answer) the hash is to be modified in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
hash = {"/help/1"=>
  ["126.318.035.038",
   "929.398.951.889",
   "543.910.244.929",
   "929.398.951.889",
   "929.398.951.889",],
 "/about"=>
   ["929.398.951.889",
   "929.398.951.889",
   "543.910.244.929",]
}
```

array of hashes of ip address with count

```
hash.transform_values {|v| v.uniq.collect{ |e| [[e, v.count(e)]].to_h } }

=> {
    "/help/1"=>[{"126.318.035.038"=>1}, 
                {"929.398.951.889"=>3}, 
                {"543.910.244.929"=>1}], 
    "/about"=>[{"929.398.951.889"=>2}, 
               {"543.910.244.929"=>1}]
   }
```

hash of ip addresses with count

```
hash.transform_values {|v| v.uniq.collect{ |e| [e, v.count(e)] }.to_h }
=> {"/help/1"=>{
                 "126.318.035.038"=>1, 
                 "929.398.951.889"=>3, 
                 "543.910.244.929"=>1}, 
    "/about"=>{
                 "929.398.951.889"=>2, 
                 "543.910.244.929"=>1}
   }
```

use below code if you have newer ruby, i have tested this on 2.7

```
hash.transform_values(&:tally)

{"/help/1"=>{
              "126.318.035.038"=>1, 
              "929.398.951.889"=>3, 
              "543.910.244.929"=>1}, 
  "/about"=>{
              "929.398.951.889"=>2, 
              "543.910.244.929"=>1}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) with a hash to which is attached a default proc that contains a second default proc.

**Code**

```
def doit(file_name)
  IO.foreach(file_name).
     with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(0) }) do |line,h|
       key, value = line.chomp.split
       h[key][value] += 1
     end
end
```

**Example**

First create a file for illustration.

```
file_name = 't'
```

```
str =<<~END
cat 1
cat 1
cat 1
cat 2
cat 2
dog 1
dog 2
dog 2
dog 3
dog 3
pig 1
pig 1
pig 1
pig 2
END
```

Randomize the lines of `str`:

```
str = str.lines.shuffle.join
  #=> "cat 1\ndog 1\npig 1\ndog 3\ncat 1\npig 1\ndog 2\ndog 2\npig 1\ncat 2\ndog 3\ncat 1\ncat 2\npig 2\n"
```

```
puts str
cat 1
dog 1
pig 1
dog 3
cat 1
pig 1
dog 2
dog 2
pig 1
cat 2
dog 3
cat 1
cat 2
pig 2
```

Create a file that contains an image of `str`:

```
File.write(file_name, str)
  #=> 84
```

Execute the method:

```
doit(file_name)
  #=> {"cat"=>{"1"=>3, "2"=>2},
  #    "dog"=>{"1"=>1, "3"=>2, "2"=>2},
  #    "pig"=>{"1"=>3, "2"=>1}}
```

Compare this with the original value of `str` above.

**Notes**

See [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) and the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that employs a default proc.

Note that because

```
IO.foreach(file_name).
   with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(0) })
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: IO:foreach("t")>:with_object({})>
```

is an enumerator, no intermediate hash (with pets as keys and arrays of strings representing non-negative integers as values) is produced, an advantage over methods that do so. Such an intermediate hash is required, for one, to use [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) (introduced in Ruby v2.7).